# How Do I make a program with Ubuntu Command Line

Tags: file-format

I want to know how to make a program that you can edit and run. The problem is I don't know what the file extension is, like how you can make a text document on windows and save as filename.bat.

Comment: I am a little unclear here. You want to make a program with Ubuntu but you want it to be a batch file you can run on Windows?

Comment: I think what you're looking for are shell scripts, with file extension .sh see https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Hello,_World!_Tutorial

Comment: Like `echo -e '#!/bin/bash\necho this is a script' > script.sh; chmod +x script.sh` ? Then run it `./script.sh` ?

Comment: @brndn2k see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31760/111181)

Comment: no, I was wondering if I could write code in a text doc within Ubuntu then run it in Ubuntu LIKE a windows batch file

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use a filename extension, but the file permission has to be set executable for the user who should be able to run it (unless you source a file in shell). See `man chmod`.

By using a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) you can tell which interpreter to use to execute a script.